# Getting picked image bytes

Tags: android, image

Hi i am picking image from gallery using this code:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);                          
            startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);


     if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) 
        {

            Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));                           
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));      
            cursor.close();
        }
```

but i am not sure if it's giving me byte size of this image, i need byte size of this picked image. Please help!

Comment: By "byte size" do you mean: byte size to show in memory, byte size of full bitmap in memory (often the same as the former), byte size on disk?

Comment: of bitmap i guess coz i want to pass this bitmap to another activity

Comment: Ooh er that makes me nervous. You probably want to do `final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); final int byteCt = bitmap.getByteCount()` - quite easy. But I should warn you, you might have a bad time passing bitmaps around in an activity. Why not pass the file path instead?

Comment: i sending this image to another phone using wifi so filepath is not good idea.

Comment: @user3465277, actually you need only file path here, so that you can `create a file connection` with that image using this path and now you can send this file to another phone using wifi..

Comment: Then stream the bytes over http from the file path in the new activity. For performance reasons, and old phone support, don't risk the bitmap parceling!

Comment: I think @Kanak Sony and I agree. We'll save you some pain.